# DLL for runtime and editor code in unity3d

Tags: unity, c#

Currently I am creating DLL of my scripts file. There are some editor script and some scripts
are using on runtime. So i have created two dlls. One for Editor the other one is for runtime.
But here comes the problem some runtime scripts contain UNITY_EDITOR directives. And here is the example code where i have stuck

```
 public void CreateNewTrigger()
        {
            GameObject t = new GameObject();
            t.name = "Trigger " + triggers.Count.ToString();
            t.transform.SetParent(transform, false);
            t.AddComponent<BoxCollider>().isTrigger = true;
            STrigger trig = t.AddComponent<STrigger>();
            trig.myZone = this;
            trig.name = t.name;
            triggers.Add(trig);

#if UNITY_EDITOR
        UnityEditor.Selection.activeObject = t;
#endif
        }
```

As you know that one specific line is under UNITY_EDITOR Directive, it should be run on editor. How do i control it?
I mean i have included aboved function into runtime scripts dll but when i am building the player its saying cant Use UnityEditor

Comment: Why would you move your script files to DLLs?

Comment: Just to add a security layer to my code.

Comment: Security against what? Players decompiling your code? DLLs can be compiled just as easily as asset files.